# Python 2.7 classes: __main__ message when trying to run a class

Tags: python, class, program-entry-point, nameerror

I have made a nice class and 2 functions that I would like to run when the survey_name 'mikkel' is entered. But when try to print Survey_route('mikkel') I get the following message:

```
<__main__.SurveyRoute object at 0x10eb0cf38>
```

What do I need to change to print *xcoord* and *the plot* when the class is run?

```
class SurveyRoute(SurveyPlotWidget):
    """docstring for SurveyRoute"""

    def __init__(self, survey_name):
        self.survey_name = survey_name

    def read_coordinate_file(self, survey_name):
        """
        coords  is a library with 'benchmark nr': UTM X, UTM Y, depth

        The coordinate name should be changed to the coordinate type. Here we are dealing with UTM coordinates
        The coordinate type can be found in the .xls file that contains the coordinates. e.g. mikkel.xls

        df      is the result of using the pandas package to rearrange the coords dictionary.
        """ 
        coords = station_coordinates.get_coordinates_all(survey_name)
        df = pd.DataFrame(coords,index=['UTM X','UTM Y','depth']) 
        df = DataFrame.transpose(df)
        xcoord = df['UTM X'].values.tolist() 
        ycoord = df['UTM Y'].values.tolist()

        print xcoord        

    def plot_coords(xcoord,ycoord):

        fig = plt.figure()
        plt.plot(xcoord, ycoord, marker='o', ms=10, linestyle='', alpha=1.0, color='r', picker = True)[0]
        plt.xlabel('UTM x-coordinate')
        plt.ylabel('UTM y-coordinate')

        x_legend = np.nanmax(xcoord) + 0.01*(np.nanmax(xcoord)-np.nanmin(xcoord))
        y_legend = np.nanmin(ycoord) - 0.01*(np.nanmax(ycoord)-np.nanmin(ycoord))
        map_size = np.sqrt(pow(np.nanmax(xcoord)-np.nanmin(xcoord),2)+pow(np.nanmax(ycoord)-np.nanmin(ycoord),2) )

        #legend_size = 100
        #max_val = np.nanmax(val)
        #if max_val < 50:
        #legend_size = 10
        fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', on_hover)
        self.canvas.draw()

"""
Set package_directory to the right user (e.g. DJV) and the folder where the station_coordinates are stored.  
"""
package_directory = '/Users/DJV/Desktop/quad-master/station_coordinates'                                     

#survey = SurveyRoute('mikkel')
#print SurveyRoute('mikkel')
#print survey.read_coordinate_file('mikkel') WORKS
#print survey.plot_coords(xcoord,ycoord)  DOESNT WORK

print SurveyRoute('mikkel')
```

Comment: thats not an error!!! thats the class instance that you printed!!! what do you exactly  want?

Comment: What did you expect to be printed instead?

Comment: Why do you think that is an error? It doesn't say error, or give you a nice red traceback.

Comment: its not an error. my bad. I changed the question. What I want is code that plots xcoord and ycoord when the survey_name is specified. displaying xcoord serves to check if the file was correctly imported.

Answer (score 0):

> SurveyRoute('mikkel')

returns an object. So when you call

> print SurveyRoute('mikkel')

you are printing the entire object. 
To print xcoord when the class is run, put this in your __ init __ function:

> self.read_coordinate_file(survey_name)

and replace

> print SurveyRoute('mikkel')

with

> SurveyRoute('mikkel')

Comment: If you want to call an `SurveyRoute` object (i.e. `sr = SurveyRoute(); sr('foo')`, you have to overwrite the `__call__` method in `SurveyRoute`

Answer (score 0):

When you do - `SurveyRoute('mikkel')` - it creates the instance/object of class `SurveyRoute` , with the `self.survey_name` equal to `mikkel` . When you try to print the object itself, it prints like you observed - `<__main__.SurveyRoute object at 0x10eb0cf38>` .

Also, if `plot_coords()` is an instance method (I believe so, as I can see you using `self` inside the function) , then the first parameter for this should be the instance (`self`). You should define this as -

```
def plot_coords(self, xcoord, ycoord):
```

If you want to call the function for this object, you should call it as -

```
obj = SurveyRoute('mikkel')
obj.read_coordinate_file(<parameter survery_name>)
obj.plot_coords(<parameters for xcoord and ycoord>)
```

Comment: first of all, thanks for spotting the self :)  second. I still have trouble defining <parameters for xcoord and ycoord > . I am now calling them like obj.plot_coords(xcoord, ycoord) which obviously doesn't work. How should I define and/or call them?

Comment: @leermeester That is how you call the function, if you have put the `self` in the definition , calling should not cause any issues, are you getting any errors? If so, maybe some other error from inside the function?

Comment: I have decided to structure the code differently such that def plot_coords(self) should do the plotting. now trying to access a local variable from a previous function in a new function.  different problem.